# Ошибка при подключении libcurl

Tags: c++, c

Не могу подключить библиотеку libcurl. Мои действия:

1. скачал саму библиотеку;
2. распаковал в /mingw32;
3. попробовал компилировать тестовый пример;

Выдало:

```
D:\ВК БОТ>mingw32-gcc main.c -l curl -l curldll
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsvfphE.o:main.c:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to '_imp__curl_global_init'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsvfphE.o:main.c:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to '_imp__curl_easy_init' 
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

D:\ВК БОТ>mingw32-gcc main.c
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cc7bs8Sk.o:main.c:(.text+0x8e): undefineв reference to '_imp__curl_global_init'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cc7bs8Sk.o:main.c:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to '_imp__curl_easy_init'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Я не с Windows, но вроде в gcc опция `-l<libname>` пишется слитно?

Comment: `D:\ВК БОТ>mingw32-gcc main.c -lcurl -lcurldll
    C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIpNp9A.o:main.c:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to '_imp__curl_global_init'
    C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIpNp9A.o:main.c:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to '_imp__curl_easy_init'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: На англоязычной версии советуют добавить папку с библиотеками вот такой опцией `-lcurl -L"c:\libcurl\lib"`

Comment: Что такое `curldll `?

Comment: это либа name:libcurldll.a

Comment: SBKarr, одно и тоже

Comment: Как собрана CURL, как DLL или статической?

Comment: Она не собрана, а просто скачана готовой)